# Unable to attach database in Amazon RDS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds

I'm trying to detach and attach a database in AWS RDS. I'm able to detach the database without any issues. But while I try to attach the database, I'm getting few errors.

When I run the attach command for the first time, I get the following error:

> Unable to create database: User, group, or role 'sa' already exists in the current database.

When I execute for the second time, I get this:

> Msg 1802, Level 16, State 7.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
>
> Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101.
>   Unable to open the physical file "D:\RDSDBDATA\DATA\DBattachTest.mdf". Operating system error 2: "2(The system cannot find the file specified.)". (Line 6)

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but you should be using *backup* and *restore* functionality to move DBs around. Attach and detach will not work as they do in a traditional SQL environment: RDS is a managed service and you have extremely limited access to the underlying OS.

From [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Using.Restore):

> ## Restoring a Database
>
> To restore your database, you call the rds_restore_database stored procedure.
>
> The following parameters are required:
>
> > #### @restore_db_name – The name of the database to restore.
> >
> > #### @s3_arn_to_restore_from – The Amazon S3 bucket that contains the backup file, and the name of the file.
> >
> > The following parameters are optional:
> >
> > #### @kms_master_key_arn – If you encrypted the backup file, the key to use to decrypt the file.
> >
> > Example Without Encryption

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database 
    @restore_db_name='database_name', 
    @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/file_name_and_extension';
```

> Example With Encryption

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database 
    @restore_db_name='database_name', 
    @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/file_name_and_extension',
    @kms_master_key_arn='arn:aws:kms:region:account-id:key/key-id';
```

Comment: Thank you @Raf. I was wondering if I can detach i should be able to attach as well. I am just started playing with rds and this came up. Like you said, i guess we are not given appropriate permissions to reach the OS and get the files back to attach. I appreciate your response!